# How come there is no 64bit build of R for Windows?

Tags: windows, r, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

How come R does not have a 64bit windows pre-built binaries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Update*

Current versions of R for Windows (since R 2.11) do come with 64-bit executables.

In the past no suitable free compiler was available. Quoting from the old R-on-Windows FAQ (taken from the sources and hence with texinfo markup):

> To build a 64-bit version on 64-bit Windows you will need a suitable 
>   compiler, and experiments with the Mingw64 port of @code{binutils} and
>   @code{gcc} have failed to produce a working version on R.  You are of
>   course welcome to try a commercial compiler@footnote{such as those from
>   Intel and PGI: there is no Fortran compiler in the Microsoft set, but
>   @code{f2c} could be used.}, and pre-compiled versions using such
>   compilers are available from R redistributors.

REvolution Computing had a Windows 64 bit version in their commercial / enterprise product before the official R gained 64-bit support.

Comment: This is very good news. I found that is already devel version, I gave a link cause its not so simple to find http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows64/contrib/

Answer (score 3):

there is now! check the cran

Answer (score 1):

[These folks](http://www.revolution-computing.com/products/windows-64bit.php) claimed they "ported" 1,500 packages to create their 64-bit version of R. If that's true, then the level of effort required might be part of the explanation why there is no free version available.

If you're not asking for a free download, the same source seems to be offering it, although commercially.